# Volttron EnergyPlus Integration idf problems

Tags: agent, volttron, energyplus

i worked through the example configuration delivered with the energyplus agent that comes with volttron. BUt now if i try to use a different idf file i get the following error:

(energyplusagent-0.1 13966)  INFO: ['Processing Input File']
2023-09-12 16:09:51,062 (energyplusagent-0.1 13966)  INFO: ['**FATAL:IP: Errors occurred on processing IDF file. Preceding condition(s) cause termination.']
2023-09-12 16:09:51,062 (energyplusagent-0.1 13966)  INFO: ['EnergyPlus Run Time=00hr 00min  0.13sec']

Is this because the idf file i tried is for a newer version of energyplus? If so how could i fix this? Is Volttron/the Energyplus Agent compatible with newer versions of Energyplus or do I have to change the idf file to one for version 8.5.0?

Thanks in advance